# What's the best way to remove discolouration of scanned photographs?

Tags: post-processing, image-processing, scanning, color-correction, restoration

I'm got a batch of printed photos which I am scanning to store a digital copy of and possibly enlarge them for printing.

I've scanned them at the maximum quality (600DPI) and saved it with the least amount of compression as possible (.tiff). When I open it up in photoshop and zoom in closely, I notice that the parts which should be a solid colour is in fact not a solid colour. 
The photo looks like this:[image: "Discoloured" image - Notice how the blacks isn't exactly black - it's got this "rainbowing" effect]

What would be the best course of action to try and "solidify" the colour? I've tried going over the area with a brush with opacity set to ~12%, but obviously this did not work very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's noise.  Mostly color noise.  You can remove that in Camera Raw using the Luminance and Color Noise reduction sliders

[image]